# How to provide value to DataFormat parameter

Tags: c#, enums

I am working with a third party class that has a method looks like this:

```
public enum DataFormat
{
    Json,
    Xml
}

public string Doc(DataFormat format)
{
    // ...
}
```

What type of value is supposed to be supplied to this method?  Having trouble understanding how to use this based on the MSDN docs.

Tried this with no luck:

```
var v = Doc(Xml);
```

Comment: new ?! with 3658 reputation? Must have forgotten to have my coffee i think ...

Comment: @Noctis New to C# that is.

Comment: :) Welcome to the wonderful land of OO and strong types (seems like you're into prototypal languages otherwise :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to call it with:

```
var v = Doc(DataFormat.Xml);
```

It's just an enum, and it's the paramater.

Comment: Ok I get it.  So many ways to proceed a class with a `.` I'm learning so far with c#

Comment: Yep. Think of it like passing a property from a class. It'll be tha same. Name of the class, `.`, name of the property.